# sentence from Cambridge dictionary: ‘his’ vs. ‘he'

Tags: dictionaries

Is this sentence from Cambridge dictionary correct?

> He was there and saw what happened, so **his** is the only authentic
>   account.
>
> (from https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/authentic)

I am wondering why it says ‘his’ and not ‘he’,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence is absolutely fine. The pronoun *his* in there is [**a possessive pronoun**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns/pronouns-possessive-my-mine-your-yours-etc) and it refers to the account that belongs to the guy they're talking about. It's basically short for *his account*. So, they actually could just as easily have said the following and there would have been no semantic difference whatsoever:

> He was there and saw what happened, so **his account** is the only authentic account.

Compare your example with this:

> Your car is red while **mine** is the only green car here.

Think of *mine* as short for *my car* because that's what the possessive pronoun *mine*, as is evident from the context of the sentence, is really referring to.